# Portainer with docker-compose and volumes fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[The Portainer docs are saying](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html):

> The `-v /opt/portainer:/data` option will persist Portainer data in `/opt/portainer` on the host where Portainer is running. You can specify another location on your filesystem.

I just created the following docker-compose:

```
portainer:
  image: portainer/portainer
  container_name: portainer
  volumes:
    - /opt/portainer:/data
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  ports:
    - 9000:9000
```

But I don't get a folder `/opt/portainer`. It seems, that the volume configuration does not work as described in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker-compose` is expecting the `/opt/portainer` folder to exist first. Once you create that, you should stop getting the error.

Comment: I used the volumes-option quite a lot before. I'm not sure that I ever created the folder first. But that works. Gosh.